# Flutter. How can I get IconData from SvgPicture?

Tags: flutter, dart

So, I use toggle_switch in my current project as it makes creation of toggles pretty much easier, but as I want to add icons to these buttons, they require me to give them IconData. But the deal is I work with SvgPictures and they have another type from what it needs. So how can I change it's type to IconData?

I was trying to use SvgPicture inside of Icon widget, but it doesn't work.